# how to write a CLI script to Enable Function Application Authentication to use Microsoft Azure AD ID Provider

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cli

Can anyone help me how to write a CLI script to Enable Function Application Authentication to use Microsoft Azure AD ID Provider?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have tested in our local environment , using the below cmdlets we are able to create Microsoft identity provider authentication for the function app & these cmdlets are working fine.

Below are the steps to be followed:

1. You Need to create a app registration in AAD & add the required permissions to that app registration using the below cmdlet.

   ```
   az ad app create --display-name <NameofappRegistration> --password <clientsecret> --reply-urls https://<functionappName>.net/.auth/login/aad/callback --required-resource-accesses @manifest.json
   ```

The below resource access will create user.read permission to that app registration

how to declare permission in manifest.json file :

```
"requiredResourceAccess": [
        {
            "resourceAppId": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
            "resourceAccess": [
                {
                    "id": "e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d",
                    "type": "Scope"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

2. You need to add identifier-uris/application uri for that app registration.

```html
az ad app update --id <appId/clientId> --identifier-uris api://<clientId>
```

3. Creating the webapp authentication and authorization of the Microsoft identity provider for the function app to that app registration using the below cmdlet

```html
    az webapp auth microsoft update -n <functionAppName> -g <ResourceGroupName> --client-id <appRegistrationClientId> --client-secret <appresgistrationPassword>  --tenant-id <TenantID>
```

Sample Output for reference post running the above cmdlets:

[image]

Here are the reference CLI cmdlet documentation for creation of    [Microsoft auth for a webapp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/auth/microsoft?view=azure-cli-latest) & for [app registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app?view=azure-cli-latest#az_ad_app_update)