# How to add built-in authentication to an App Service using only azure CLI?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-authentication

My question would have been redundant if [Enable azure app service authentication and create app registration in azure cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75826404/enable-azure-app-service-authentication-and-create-app-registration-in-azure-cli) took it all the way to the answer. But it stops at creation of a bare app registration.

So, here I have run the following commands:

```
az webapp auth update -n my-webapp -g my-rg --enabled true --action RedirectToLoginPage --enable-token-store false
az ad app create --display-name my-app-reg
```

But how to proceed then?

**EDIT 1**

First - my Azure CLI version:

```
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$ az version
{
  "azure-cli": "2.55.0",
  "azure-cli-core": "2.55.0",
  "azure-cli-telemetry": "1.1.0",
  "extensions": {
    "aks-preview": "0.5.173",
    "application-insights": "1.0.0",
    "authV2": "0.1.3",
    "azure-devops": "0.26.0",
    "storage-preview": "1.0.0b1",
    "virtual-wan": "0.3.0"
  }
}
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$
```

Now trying to create the App Registration:

**Take 1**

```
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$ az webapp auth update -g $resourceGroupName -n $appName --enabled true --action LoginWithAzureActiveDirectory --aad-allowed-token-audiences https://$appName.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback --aad-client-id $appId --aad-client-secret $clientSecret --aad-token-issuer-url https://sts.windows.net/$tenantId/
az webapp auth update: 'LoginWithAzureActiveDirectory' is not a valid value for '--unauthenticated-client-action'. Allowed values: RedirectToLoginPage, AllowAnonymous, Return401, Return404, Return403.

Examples from AI knowledge base:
az webapp auth update -g myResourceGroup --name MyWebApp --unauthenticated-client-action AllowAnonymous
Configure the app to allow unauthenticated requests to hit the app.

az webapp auth update -g myResourceGroup --name MyWebApp --set identityProviders.azureActiveDirectory.registration.clientId=my-client-id
Update the client ID of the AAD provider already configured

az webapp auth update -g myResourceGroup --name MyWebApp --runtime-version 1.4.7
Pin the runtime version of the app to 1.4.7

https://aka.ms/cli_ref
Read more about the command in reference docs
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$
```

[image]

**Take 2**

```
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$ az webapp auth update -g $resourceGroupName -n $appName --enabled true --action RedirectToLoginPage --aad-allowed-token-audiences https://$appName.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback --aad-client-id $appId --aad-client-secret $clientSecret --aad-token-issuer-url https://sts.windows.net/$tenantId/
unrecognized arguments: --aad-allowed-token-audiences https://aida-chat-platform.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback --aad-client-id f8fe5caa-b68b-4caa-bbc2-8862bdd47c4f --aad-client-secret *** --aad-token-issuer-url https://sts.windows.net/2...b/

Examples from AI knowledge base:
az webapp auth update --name myUniqueApp --resource-group myResourceGroup
Update the authentication settings for the webapp. (autogenerated)

az webapp auth update --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myUniqueApp --action AllowAnonymous --facebook-app-id my_fb_id --facebook-app-secret my_fb_secret --facebook-oauth-scopes public_profile email
Allow Facebook authentication by setting FB-associated parameters and turning on public-profile and email scopes; allow anonymous users

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/cli/azure/webapp/auth#az_webapp_auth_update
Read more about the command in reference docs
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$
```

[image]

**EDIT 2**

I have positive progress thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/77911481/80002. My issue was that while trying all kinds of things I enabled the authV2 Azure CLI extension and that removed the `LoginWithAzureActiveDirectory` action from the list of actions supported by the `az webapp auth update` command. Once I removed that extension (`az extension remove`) I successfully ran the command proposed in that answer.

And it opens the SSO login dialog as expected, but trying to login results in this:
[image]

**EDIT 3**

So I ran the following to try and resolve the issue:

```
az ad app update --id $appId --enable-id-token-issuance true
```

Now trying to login returns a different error:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work by following these steps:

1. Create a demo App Service using instructions in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-python. The last command is `az webapp up --runtime PYTHON:3.9 --sku B1 --logs` to create the App Service itself. Verify it works.
2. Use v2 of App Service Auth config - `az webapp auth config-version upgrade --id {web app id}`
3. Enable authV2 Azure CLI extension - `az extension add -n authV2`
4. Create App Registration for the webapp - `az ad app create --display-name {App Name} --enable-id-token-issuance true --web-redirect-uris https://{web app name}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback --required-resource-accesses @manifest.json` (see manifest.json below). Notice the App Registration `appId`.
5. Reset the App Registration credentials - `az ad app credential reset --id {appId}` - notice the password.
6. Enable App Service authentication - `az webapp auth update --ids {Web App Id} --enabled true --action RedirectToLoginPage`
7. Setup Microsoft authentication using authV2 syntax - `az webapp auth microsoft update --ids {Web App Id} --client-id {appId} --client-secret {app secret} --tenant-id {Tenant Id}`

**manifest.json** (I found it in https://stackoverflow.com/a/69719989)

```
[
  {
    "resourceAppId": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
    "resourceAccess": [
      {
        "id": "e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d",
        "type": "Scope"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now let us run the steps from scratch:

```
mark@L-R910LPKW:~/work/msdocs-python-django-webapp-quickstart [main ≡]$ az webapp up --runtime PYTHON:3.9 --sku B1 --logs
The webapp 'red-water-476d8199b06644b99e3f30c29cff99d7' doesn't exist
...
Starting Live Log Stream ---
^Cmark@L-R910LPKW:~/work/msdocs-python-django-webapp-quickstart [main ≡]$
```

- App Service id: `/subscriptions/0...7/resourceGroups/ee742f99-0a52-4c3a-a3e0-a3e4bd961a1c_rg_0877/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/red-water-476d8199b06644b99e3f30c29cff99d7`
- App Service url: `https://red-water-476d8199b06644b99e3f30c29cff99d7.azurewebsites.net/`

Now let us enable authentication:

```
mark@L-R910LPKW:~/work/msdocs-python-django-webapp-quickstart [main ≡]$ id=/subscriptions/0...7/resourceGroups/ee742f99-0a52-4c3a-a3e0-a3e4bd961a1c_rg_0877/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/red-water-476d8199b06644b99e3f30c29cff99d7
mark@L-R910LPKW:~/work/msdocs-python-django-webapp-quickstart [main ≡]$ az webapp auth config-version upgrade --id $id
{
...
}
mark@L-R910LPKW:~/work/msdocs-python-django-webapp-quickstart [main ≡]$ az extension add -n authV2
Default enabled including preview versions for extension installation now. Disabled in May 2024. Use '--allow-preview true' to enable it specifically if needed. Use '--allow-preview false' to install stable version only.
Extension 'authV2' 0.1.3 is already installed.
mark@L-R910LPKW:~/work/msdocs-python-django-webapp-quickstart [main ≡]$ cat /tmp/manifest.json
[
  {
    "resourceAppId": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
    "resourceAccess": [
      {
        "id": "e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d",
        "type": "Scope"
      }
    ]
  }
]
mark@L-R910LPKW:~/work/msdocs-python-django-webapp-quickstart [main ≡]$ az ad app create --display-name "Mark Auth Test" --enable-id-token-issuance true --w
eb-redirect-uris https://red-water-476d8199b06644b99e3f30c29cff99d7.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback --required-resource-accesses @/tmp/manifest.json
{
...
}
mark@L-R910LPKW:~/work/msdocs-python-django-webapp-quickstart [main ≡]$ appId=7...c
mark@L-R910LPKW:~/work/msdocs-python-django-webapp-quickstart [main ≡]$ az ad app credential reset --id $appId
The output includes credentials that you must protect. Be sure that you do not include these credentials in your code or check the credentials into your source control. For more information, see https://aka.ms/azadsp-cli
{
...
}
mark@L-R910LPKW:~/work/msdocs-python-django-webapp-quickstart [main ≡]$ appSecret=w...4
mark@L-R910LPKW:~/work/msdocs-python-django-webapp-quickstart [main ≡]$ az webapp auth update --ids $id --enabled true --action RedirectToLoginPage
The behavior of this command has been altered by the following extension: authV2
{
...
}
mark@L-R910LPKW:~/work/msdocs-python-django-webapp-quickstart [main ≡]$ az webapp auth microsoft update --ids $id --client-id $appId --client-secret $appSecret --tenant-id $ARM_TENANT_ID
Configuring --client-secret will add app settings to the web app. Are you sure you want to continue? (y/N): y
App settings have been redacted. Use `az webapp/logicapp/functionapp config appsettings list` to view.
{
...
}
mark@L-R910LPKW:~/work/msdocs-python-django-webapp-quickstart [main ≡]$
```

And it works at least for me.

One thing that bothers me is that the Authentication page of the App Service shows a rather nasty warning:

[image]

Other than that it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

I have one App Service named **`demowebapp31`** without any authentication configured like this:

[image]

You can make use of below **CLI script** that creates azure ad app registration with client secret and adds authentication to App service:

```bash
appName="yourappname"
resourceGroupName="yourrgname"

# Create Azure AD App Registration with redirect URI
app=$(az ad app create --display-name $appName --web-redirect-uris "https://$appName.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback")
appId=$(echo $app | jq -r '.appId')
tenantId=$(az account show --query tenantId --output tsv)

clientSecretName="secret"
clientSecret=$(az ad app credential reset --id $appId --append --display-name $clientSecretName --query password --output tsv)

az webapp auth update -g $resourceGroupName -n $appName --enabled true \
  --action LoginWithAzureActiveDirectory \
  --aad-allowed-token-audiences https://$appName.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback \
  --aad-client-id $appId --aad-client-secret $clientSecret \
  --aad-token-issuer-url https://sts.windows.net/$tenantId/
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the same in Portal where authentication is added successfully to App service like this:

[image]

**References:**

[az webapp auth | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/auth?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-auth-update-examples)

[Manage AuthN/AuthZ API versions - Azure App Service | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-api-version)

Comment: Thank you very much for this prompt reply. However, the last command returns the following message - **az webapp auth update: 'LoginWithAzureActiveDirectory' is not a valid value for '--unauthenticated-client-action'. Allowed values: RedirectToLoginPage, AllowAnonymous, Return401, Return404, Return403.**

Comment: Changing LoginWithAzureActiveDirectory with RedirectToLoginPage fails with a new message - **unrecognized arguments: --aad-allowed-token-audiences https://my-app.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback --aad-client-id f8fe5caa-b68b-4caa-bbc2-8862bdd47c4f --aad-client-secret *** --aad-token-issuer-url https://sts.windows.net/2...b/**

Comment: Could you add your current code and error with  more details by editing your question with screenshots to know whether you are adding any extra parameters or not?

Comment: In my case, I'm running that script in Azure Cloud Shell with version like this https://i.imgur.com/KH5Njwc.png Could you try the same from Azure Cloud Shell and check it works? Also, what type of App service you are trying to update, with what auth settings, is it authv2 as mentioned here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/auth?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-auth-update(authv2)?

Comment: Check if this helps in authv2 scenario https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/26603#issuecomment-1600767400

Comment: I do not think it is authv2. At least I did not do anything explicit for that. I will try the Cloud shell.

Comment: OK, I did install Azure CLI authV2 extension, even if I did not use it later. But, it modified the parameters of the `az webapp auth update` command. I removed it now and so I should be able to run you example again. Let me retry.

Comment: There is progress in the right direction, please see **EDIT 2**. Thank you.

Comment: And **EDIT 3**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256744/discussion-between-sridevi-and-mark).